# ControlFx PropertySheet custom Control

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I am using ControlFx [PropertySheet](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html) in my project . I manage To get it running.
BeansObj:

```
public class BeansObj implements Serializable {  
    private String name;
    private String mail;
    private boolean smart;
    private int age;
    //Getters,Setters, Beans stuff....
}
```

ControllerClass:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private PropertySheet sheet;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
    sheet.getItems().addAll(BeanPropertyUtils  
                .getProperties(new BeansObj("foo","foo@bar.foo",true,41)));  
    }
}
```

For the boolen field, the generated control is a checkbox with an empty text;

1-How to set this text value implicitly?

For the mail field(String)

2-how to add custom validation method?

For each field

3-how to add a css class|id to specific Control?

By default(I guess) all the controls belong to the Basic Category( [PropertySheet.Mode](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.Mode.html#CATEGORY))

4-how to set the category **implicitly** or explicitly ?

and, in case BeansObj has an Collection attribute

5-how to make it generate a tableView?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So I gave up on this and made my own custom property sheet !! it's clumsy but it will do the job!!